# How to set permissions for application in Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu, permissions, linux-mint, packages

I have a quick question: suppose that, as root (or a user with high privileges), I install some package by running `sudo apt-get install somepackage`. Is there a way to block other users from launching `somepackage` in Ubuntu/Linux Mint? If so, can it be done with packages built from source as well?

Any help will be appreciated :)

Comment: Can you be more specific about why you would want to do this?  This is a bit of an unusual request.  There may be better alternatives in some situations, but I don't want to add answers that would be irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

This is accomplished by setting the file permissions using the chmod command.  In your case, you'll need to find the primary executable file for somepackage and run `chmod og-rwx somepackage` you'll probably want to set yourself as the owner so you can still use it with the following `chown <your-user-name> somepackage`.  If it's owned by root, don't forget to `sudo`.

Updated per xenoid's comment to disallow anyone from copying the file and changing permissions on this file. tested on macOS 10.12.

Comment: Not enough.... someone could still copy the file elsewhere and change the execution flag of the copy. You must make the file unreadable as well.

Comment: chmod 640 /path/to/sompackage or /path/to/somefile ;  sudo chmod +i /path/to/somepackage or /path/to/somefile ( the chmod +i enables the immutable bit once set as desired only someone in the packages' primary owner group would be able to change this, similar to a .lock file